# Load language specific response files in bot

Tags: botframework

How to load the locale specific responses from the response json files ? e.g https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/samples/assistants/HospitalitySample/Responses/Escalate , there are files created for different locales. Not sure how can I load them ? There is a method, ResponseManager.GetResponseTemplate which takes locale as parameter, i have tried that but not loading the right response file. Thanks for your help.

I have same question there for adpative card json file load. https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/tree/master/samples/assistants/HospitalitySample/Content

Comment: Got the documentation and good to go, https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/handbook/localization/ , https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/handbook/language-generation/

Answer (score 0):

Got it cleared from this documentations,

https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/skills/handbook/language-generation/

https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/virtual-assistant/handbook/localization/